# How to release the memory in Master View Controller(First View Controller) in the application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While we returning back to the 2nd view controller to main view controller, The Dealloc method is called and all the allocated memory is released of that view  controller that is 2nd view controller.
Then when will the dealloc method is called of Master View Controller that is First view contoller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be deallocated when the application finishes or when the First View Controller is released.